# Sort Column of Pivot table Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I'm trying to sort the columns of a pivot table in a specific order, not alphabetical. In my table, I have the same values on the x and y axis and the values are the similarity between them. I have the order of the y axis sorted in a specific order and would like the x axis of values to match, so that the diagonal of values will be all 1.0. Below is an example of what I'm doing, with example data

```
# Code to create pivot table
pivot=final_df.groupby(['Fruit A','Fruit B'], sort=False)['Similarity Score'].sum().unstack('Fruit B')
```

|  | Apple | Orange | Mango | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | 0.4 | 1 | 0.6 | 0.7 |
| Mango | 0.3 | 0.4 | 1 | 0.5 |
| Apple | 1 | 0.3 | 0.6 | 0.1 |
| Banana | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.5 | 1 |

Ideally, I want the above table to also say orange, mango, apple, banana (in that order) on the column labels, resulting in 1 throughout the diagonal. How can I do this effectively?

Answer (score 0):

One option: use an ordered [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) for your two fruits columns.

```
order = ['Orange', 'Mango', 'Apple', 'Banana']
df['Fruit A'] = pd.Categorical(df['Fruit A'], categories=order, ordered=True)
df['Fruit B'] = pd.Categorical(df['Fruit B'], categories=order, ordered=True)
# then pivot
```

Second option: [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
order = ['Orange', 'Mango', 'Apple', 'Banana']
pivot.reindex(index=order, columns=order)
```